# Cursor change while hovering over shiny widget

Tags: r, shiny

I am using a simple slider bar in a shiny app to define a value range. I have noticed that you can quite usefully slide the range without changing the start and end value individually (by holding the blue region of the slider bar). However, when I have implemented this feature, users have complained that this functionality is not obvious.

To make this functionality more obvious, I would like the cursor to change to a 'move' symbol [e.g.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBSgT.png) when the the cursor hovers over the blue region.

Here is some simple code to modify.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = 'slider1', 
              label = 'slider input',
              min = 0, max =100, 
              value = c(10,90)
              )  
)
server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do this.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(
    '#test {
    cursor: crosshair;
    color: red;
    }'
  ),

  div(id="test",sliderInput(inputId = 'slider1', 
                            label = 'slider input',
                            min = 0, max =100, 
                            value = c(10,90))
  )  
)
server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This code changes the cursor inside a div with the slider, and the cursor still reverts to the special shiny slider cursor when you hover over the blue bar. In the shiny source code there is already a unique cursor programmed for the slider, so I don't think you will be able to override that, at least not easily.